# Can not stop/remove docker containers and Images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We have few old elasticsearch version containers (installed by a vendor many years ago) that need to be removed completely.I've no information as to how these containers were created initially. Stopping or killing these container/s using stop/kill/remove commands doesn’t exit its status(Remains Up) & hence can't remove them. Please share how to totally remove these images/containers.

There are other newer elasticsearch versioned containers on it, viz we installed later that are to be retained. They gets in exited status fine on stopping but not the ones we want to delete.

Tried below commands.

"docker stop "   -- Status remains up & a new containerID gets assigned to it

"docker kill "   -- Status remains up & a new containerID gets assigned to it

"docker rmi -f "     -- untags image, assigns a temporary ImageID and assign back ImageName on removing the temporary ImageID

"docker system prune"    -- do not helps

"systemctl daemon-reload & systemctl restart docker"  --Do not helps

"docker node ls"         --Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager.

"docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q)" -- do not helps.They still restarts

Comment: Have you tried `docker system prune --all --force --volumes`? -- be careful, this will remove ALL images and containers!

Comment: Executing this command results in untagging, deleting and reclaiming some space. However on further executing docker ps -a , all the containers still exists and are up

Comment: If we assume it is Kubernetes which is recreating the containers, then how can kubernetes configuration file be found which is responsible for recreating the containers(May be we need to comment out the replication controller or load balancer that is recreating the containers in the kubernetes config file) and then run the docker commands again to stop the containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'sudo systemctl restart docker' didn't worked however stopping & starting commands individually, like below, let the containers go. But on restarting the machine, these container & images reappeared again. so it's not a perfect solution.

```
Sudo systemctl stop docker  --This stopped docker Then starting the docker properly
Sudo systemctl start docker
```

Once up, the unneeded containers were gone

Next, unneeded images could be removed by
Sudo docker image rm